# Disabled wxWidgets menu on MacOS

Tags: macos, cmake, wxwidgets

I use CMake to build Mac application using wxWidgets 3.1.3.

I'm using standard `wxMenu` to create menu, it works well on Windows and Linux but on MacOS after start the application the menu is disabled until change focus to another application and back.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```cpp
wxMenu* menuFile = new wxMenu;
wxMenu* menuHelp= new wxMenu;
// fill the menus ...
wxMenuBar* menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
menuBar->Append(menuFile, "&File");
menuBar->Append(menuHelp, "&Help");
SetMenuBar(menuBar);
```

Comment: can you build and run the `minimal` sample provided with the wxWidgets?

Comment: yes, I've built `menu` sample on MacOS. There are two executables: `menu` and `menu.app`. The first one works with the same issue as mine app (menu is disabled) but the second one works fine.

Comment: you absolutely should build the Mac OSX Application Bundle if you plan it to work on every single OSX. Besides it is an official way to distribute progrqms on OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MaxOS bundle should be set in CMakeLists.txt script:

```
if(APPLE)
    set_target_properties(app-target PROPERTIES
        MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
        XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "" # to disable code sign
    )
endif()
```

Now MacOS application will be created (.app) instead of just an executable.

This also solves problem with appearing console when launching from Finder.